# Generating password protected zip files from ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zip

Has anyone had any luck creating password protected zip files in rails?

I spent a bunch of hours trying to get Chilkat's 64 bit linux gem working on OSX. I got it listed as installed in my gem list, but I was never able to instantiate anything.

I'm on 1.9.2, 3.2.3, OSX.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried ZipRuby? It seems to have an [encryption method](https://bitbucket.org/winebarrel/zip-ruby/wiki/Home).

```
Zip::Archive.encrypt('filename.zip', 'password')
```

Sorry haven't tried it myself so can't be absolutely sure.

Comment: Fantastic! Not sure how that gem got past me, but it works perfectly. Thanks very much for the tip!

Comment: Glad it helped, if you need to go gem hunting in the future, try here https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/

Comment: This link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using the [RubyZip](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip) library. Note that, as of now, it's marked as "Experimental". But it works. Also note that AES encryption is not yet supported.

https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip#password-protection-experimental