# RAILS: zip files protected with password

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code in my controller, and wanted to make the zip files is protected with password.

i have tried with this solution from rubyzip  https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip#password-protection-experimental but no luck. is there anyway i can achieve that?

```
def export
  @user = current_user
  @user_gdpr_profile = @user.gdpr || @user.build_gdpr

  # CSV File 1: user_profile
  if @user.user_profile.present?
    headers = UserProfile.new.attributes.keys
    headers.delete('created_at')
    logger.info "headers: #{headers.inspect}"
    res = CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << headers
      csv << headers.map{ |attr|
        value = @user.user_profile.send(attr.to_sym)
        value
      }
    end
  else
    res = nil
  end

  zipfile_name = "#{Rails.root}/public/#{@user.email}.zip"

  Zip::File.open(zipfile_name, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|
    zipfile.get_output_stream("user_profile.csv") { |f| f.write res }
  end

  send_file(File.join("#{Rails.root}/public/", "#{@user.email}.zip"), :type => 'application/zip', filename: "#{@user.email}.zip")
  file = "#{@user.email}.zip"

end
```

**update[0]**

i did follow from [Generating password protected zip files from ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494403/generating-password-protected-zip-files-from-ruby-on-rails) but its kinda outdated, so not working in my latest rails 5 and ruby 2.5.1

**update[01]**

i tried with:

```
Zip::OutputStream.write_buffer(::StringIO.new(''), Zip::TraditionalEncrypter.new('password')) do |zos|
  zos.put_next_entry("user_profile.csv")
  zos.write res
end.string
```

it saved but can't open the zip file. do i did something wrong somewhere in my code?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip#password-protection-experimental

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes, i tried that before in my above code, but the zip files still doesn't  get encrypted

Comment: You used it in the above code? I don't see it. The code has nothing related to encryption.

Comment: I suggest you cut all of the irrelevant stuff: your controller code, your user-profile-to-csv transformation, __everything__ not directly related to generation of a zip file. It only distracts the reader.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i mean, it was using before. let me update the code above

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i've updated my question above. thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Indeed, that code doesn't work for me too.

Comment: Ah, never mind, was stupid mistake on my part. This worked for me: https://gist.github.com/stulentsev/108ab09c52458d9d04d7b0513167b1f9 Try it and report.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, your solution that my_file.txt got encrypted right? what i want is the zip file itself is encrypted with the password

Comment: Yes, the whole zip file is encrypted. You didn't try it, did you?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev opss sorry.. i was looking at the wrong file. it works. please post as answer and i will accept it.. thanks alot

Comment: Nah, it turned out to be a dupe after all.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev if so, just many thanks for you for your help.

Comment: And thanks to you I learned how to make encrypted zip files. Might come in handy someday :)